# SSIS BlobTempStorage Issue

Tags: ssis

I have been facing the below issue for quite some time, any help is really appreciated.

I have a SSIS package, Which does a simple Data Transform\Transfer between 2 database.
As a best practice, i have assigned a BlobTempStorage path on the DFT task(as one of the column is of type XML).

The package executes fine when i run it from my Local machine from Visual Studio.

By when configured on the Servers, i get the below issue :
Description: Failed to retrieve long data for column "X_Data". Where X_Data is my Xml Column.

Checked the Physical drive for the BlobtempStorage, the is no space issues. i have more than 200 GB available on the drive.

The account from which the Job is scheduled has Read\Write access on the folder.

One thing i found is if i upgrade the account with Admin privileges , i could see that job executes fine, but not when it has only Read\Write access on the folder.

Please help me here.. I cannot create a Admin account on the production server and without admin account its not working, i am sure i missing out on something.